# the only way is if~

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals

> I have never gotten to listen to one of those Parental Warning CDs, because Mom and Dad never let me buy them at the mall. So I realized **the only way** I was gonna get a chance to listen to Rodrick's CD **was if** I snuck it out of the house. (from Diary of a Wimpy Kid by Jeff Kinney)

**The only way I was gonna get a chance to listen to Rodrick's CD was if I snuck it out of the house.**

The use of "if" above is grammatical and correct? As far as I know, "If" has two uses.

1. used in conditional clauses as adverbial clauses
2. used in interrogative clauses as nominal clauses(in this case, if the clause is used as an object, "if" can be replaced by "whether". More importantly, "if" clause cannot be in a 'subject complement' position)

I am confused about which category the "if" above falls under. 1) or 2) or nothing? The "if" clause above is a nominal clause, but at the same time, has a conditional meaning. Also, it is in a subject complement position.

Is this use of "if" grammatical? correct? idiomatic? or just colloquial and informal?

Comment: Good question. 'The only way ... is if ...' is certainly used quite commonly. 'The only way [we can do this] is to ...' is a work-around that's certainly grammatical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your reply. I got that 'The only way ... is if ...' is used frequently, maybe in informal situations. Then, is the structure grammatical or not?

Comment: The way these things are actually tested is by asking panels of able (and proved as such)  Anglophones (perhaps graduate linguists) to vote on the grammaticality of individual sentences. With trickier examples such as this, there might well be a finding such as '65% of the panel said that ...'. I'm not aware of pronouncements on the 'The only way ... is if ...' string.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I appreciate your kind answer.

Comment: *The only way is [**to** use Google NGrams*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=only+way+is+if%2Conly+way+is+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conly%20way%20is%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20way%20is%20to%3B%2Cc0) to compare relative prevalence of *the only way is **if** [you do something]* to *the only is **to** [do something]*. From which it's clear the "infinitive verb" construction is far more common.

Comment: This is spoken English. It is very common. The only way is if [something]. The only way refers to something earlier in the conversation. **If I snuck it out of the house, I was going to get a chance to listen, etc**. It's conditional and fine.

Comment: I found David Attenborough quoted in the Daily Telegraph: "The only acceptable way is if you can persuade people to have fewer children."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction is fairly common in print. Some examples appear to be formal writing, and I see nothing wrong with them:

> But how can all of 5.1-5.5 be true? The only way is if the
> following is also true:  [*Commonsense Consequentialism*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Commonsense_Consequentialism/eoI95AM9AAUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20only%20way%20is%20if%22&pg=PA130&printsec=frontcover) (2011) p.130

> The only way this will find concrete, tangible, and long-term
> expression in society and community—in our world—is if you learn how to work with
> others and form a society—a guild, a school, a hospital...
> *[Institutional Intelligence](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Institutional_Intelligence/FvMtDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20only%20way%20will%20be%20if%22&pg=PA6&printsec=frontcover)* (2017) p.6-7.

In the first example, one could say *...is by accepting the following as true,* but the point may be that the "following" is *not* true (and 5.1-5.5 are not all true as a consequence). The *if* construction does a better job in that case.

In the second example, one could replace *...is if you learn how ...* with *...is by learning how* or *...is to learn how...* But they are not exactly the same -- the conditionality feels weaker.

**The only way the party will be a success is if Susan comes** can't be transformed with *...to have Susan come* or *....by having Susan come*. They both imply Susan hasn't been invited. *...to ensure/by ensuring Susan comes* do imply she's been invited, but they also have a different meaning.

Comment: I like your "party" example - I find it interesting that there doesn't seem to be any simple transformation of *the only way ... is **if** Susan comes* that retains the specific implication. Perhaps I should say *lack* of implication, since only ***if*** seems compatible with the fully "agnostic" position - both as regards whether or not Susan has been invited, *and* as regards who might influence / decide on her possible presence (Susan, or those discussing her).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that's the case. One could say "**Only if** Susan comes to the party will it be a success." For example, I found "...because only if we know what the threat is, can we decide what submarine we need." in a transcript.  (I don't know if a comma  is necessary after *party* here.) I think *the only way* is stronger and less formal than *only if* plus inversion.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the construction is perfectly acceptable English. Grammatically, the *if* clause in your case is a **preposition phrase** (PP).

**Discussion**

While [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) doesn't explicitly treat this very construction, some things it does say are highly relevant.

The most important takeaway from CGEL is the following: except in cases where it is interchangeable with *whether,* the word *if* is a **preposition** and it functions as the [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of a **preposition phrase.** From p. 600:

> We therefore include in the preposition category all of the
> subordinating conjunctions of traditional grammar, with three
> exceptions. The exceptions are, first, *whether*; second, those
> occurrences of *if* that are equivalent to *whether* (as in *Ask him
> if he minds*); and, third, *that* when it introduces a subordinate
> clause. These items we take to be markers of subordination, not heads
> of the constructions in which they figure: see Ch. 11, §8.1, for
> detailed discussion of this issue.

This is one of the more significant differences between CGEL and traditional grammar; its defense in CGEL runs on several pages.

Once it is accepted, however, the grammar of your sentence becomes less mysterious.

Preposition phrases routinely function as complements of the verb ***be.*** Probably the most frequent case is that of **location complements,** as in

[1] *The letter is **on the table.***

More relevantly, we have

*The only way is **over the plain** or **along the shore.*** [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Adventures_of_Elizabeth_in_R%C3%BCgen/-RHDDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the%20only%20way%20is%22)
*The only way is **by setting an example.*** (from [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/))
*The only way is **by boat.*** [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Girl_Detective_Megapack/MSSwAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22only%20way%20is%20by%20boat%22)

Conversely, note that some other noun phrases also licence *if* PP complements (all examples are from [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)):

*The only danger we have is **if they manage to produce our energy weapons and make them more powerful.***
*The only explanation that would justify it, in my eyes, is **if there's a billion dollars hidden in that painting.***
*The worst cost is **if you're perceived as covering something up.***

**In conclusion:** the construction *the only way*+***be*** licenses a variety of PP complements, including *if*-phrases.

Comment: Wow, this really helps my understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is** the use of "if" above grammatical and correct?

Yes.

> *The only way I was gonna get a chance to listen to Rodrick's CD was if I snuck it out of the house.*

if I snuck it out of the house, is an adjectival clause and the complement of "The only way [...] was".

It is clearer without the relative clause *"[that] I was gonna get a chance to listen to Rodrick's CD"*:

*The only way [...] was if I snuck it out of the house.*

Comment: What is your ground for thinking that "if I snuck it out of the house" is an adjectival clause? A clause after "be" can be a nominal clause or an adjectival clause. Why do you think that the "if" clause is not a nominal clause?

Comment: If the if clause were nominal, you would be able to use it as the subject of a sentence.

Comment: I got to some degree why the "if" clause cannot be nominal. But it doesn't necessarily mean the "if" clause is adjectival. Isn't it that also an adverbial clause can be placed after "be"?

Comment: *Isn't it that also an adverbial clause can be placed after "be"?* Yes, but that depends on what the verb "be" means in the context. In this context, it seems to be stative and the phrase adds meaning to"the way".